# Simple, wrapping red validation message in java swing

Tags: java, swing, validation, validationmessage

So I've been developing web applications for 10 years, but have fond memories of working on small swing applications that related to an introductory programming curriculum I was paid to help with before that. I generally like building swing/java UI especially with a decent UI builder. However, in the intervening time I've become very accustomed to providing clear, red error messages of variable length and number when the data on a form is invalid. Sometimes with icons, sometimes with markers on the field etc. Very common stuff that's easy to do in the web world, and is really helpful and improves usability.

Today I was trying to find a way to display a nice list of error messages at the top or bottom of my swing form, icons and field markers can come later, but for now I just want a nice variable sized list of things that need to be corrected, in a red color.

At first blush this seems like it would be easy, but..

- JLabel doesn't wrap, so long text is hidden, or you have to make the form ultra wide
- JText Area has the same issue unless you define a number of columns, and I want to fill the space available. A set number of columns won't resize.
- JTextPane wraps but as far as I can tell it won't turn red unless you get into the whole way over complicated StyledDocument bit. I don't want to do anything more complicated than change the text color so this seems like overkill.

There's also the minor issue of pushing outside the window space, and one can call pack(), but Id like to only increase the height of the form and wrap the text not change the dialog to the width of the message (creating lots of strained layout and dead space if a single long message doubles the width)

I also don't really want to have scroll bars either for the message area or the form as a whole.

This surely is a wheel that's already been invented, so what's the right way to show a list of red (but otherwise unformatted) error messages in a swing form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Label doesn't wrap, so long text is hidden, or you have to make the
>   form ultra wide

- use [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

> JText Area has the same issue unless you define a number of columns,
>   and I want to fill the space available. A set number of columns won't
>   resize.

- use word and line wrap

> A set number of columns won't resize. and together with "I also don't really want to have scroll bars"

- put JTextArea to JScrollPane, to disable JScrollBars, set null for Borders from JScrollPane

> JTextPane wraps but as far as I can tell it won't turn red unless you
>   get into the whole way over complicated StyledDocument bit. I don't
>   want to do anything more complicated than change the text color so
>   this seems like overkill.

- use HighLighter, but nothing clear from posted description about your issue with StyledDocument

Comment: huh I must be blind, I looked for a property relating to wrapping on text area and missed it somehow. The HTML in labels I didn't realize was possible I thought you needed a JTextPane or JEditorPane for that. Thanks